# Контрольные суммы кредитных карт

Tags: python, валидация

Какие существуют на данный момент алгоритмы проверки номера кредитной карты на валидность с помощью вычисления контрольной суммы и есть ли у них реализация на Python.

Comment: [алгоритм Луна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: Читал что он допускает ошибки

Comment: да, допускает. Грубо коворя, последняя цифра - это просто хешсумма предыдущих. Так как множество 15 цифр сильно больше 10, то ошибки - это нормально.

Comment: @LorDo он просто подтверждает, что выбранная последовательность цифр имеет право быть номером карты. Вы хотите, чтобы был алгоритм, способный проверить факт выдачи карты просто на основе математических вычислений? Это невозможно.

Comment: Меня вполне устраивает, что он делает в данный момент, просто хотелось бы максимально снизить вероятность ошибки, можно ли использовать для этих целей Алгоритм Верхуффа ?

Comment: алгоритм то можно применить, но только в номере кредитки оно не сохраняется.
Самый надежный способ проверить карточку - это спросить у банка - карточка может оказаться исправной, но только выданной десять лет назад или баланс в глубоком минусе - а по номеру это не понятно.

Вот именно по этому, многие компании, которым нужно проверить карточку, резервируют на ней 1 долл/гривну/евро и потом через час-два отпускают.

Comment: Цель задачи максимально точно проверить по номеру карты ее валидность (т.е. может ли является этот набор цифр номером карты), меня интересует какой алгоритм на данный момент более эффективен для этой задачи

Answer (score 1):

**CRC** или **циклический избыточный код** предназначен для проверки целостности данных. Различных вариаций на эту тему множество, как и их комбинаций. Самый простой алгоритм используется для подсчёта контрольной цифры штрих-кода.

1. Цифры набора нумеруются справа налево.
2. Подсчитываются суммы цифр, стоящих на четных и нечетных местах.
3. Сумма цифр, стоящих на четных местах, суммируется с утроенной суммой цифр, стоящих на нечетных местах.
4. Если цифра единиц полученного результата равна нулю, то контрольная цифра - 0. Если последняя цифра результата не нуль, то контрольная цифра равна дополнению этой цифры до 10.